# embed large PDFs retrieved from rest API

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I have a rest API that reads a pdf file content as bytes, encode it to base64 and send it back as encoded data. on the client side I have an embed tag and a function that adds the retrieved data from the rest api as

`src="data:application/pdf;base64," + pdfDataEncodedAsBase64`.

this works great for most PDFs. the problem is that after quite some investigation, this approach does not work for PDFs larger than 1.5 MBs

according to this rfc https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397  The **data:** URL scheme is only useful for short values. any other suggestions on how to embed such pdfs?.

I can't use `PDF.js` because it has lot's of limitations, like it is not supported inside embed tag and I need to embed (not open in a new window) the pdfs.

Comment: Can you turn it into a Blob?

Comment: I can, I tried this approach also. pdfDatablob = new blob([dataSentFromServer], {type: "application/pdf"}) then adding this as the src attribute for my embed tag. but this fails for all pdfs. am I doing it wrong?

Comment: In what format does the data come from the server? Already as a file?

Comment: it is sent as `Base64Encoded` @Luca

Comment: I am using asp.net web APIs, I convert the bytes of the pdf file to array, encode them to base64string then use this as the string content for HttpResponseMessage with headers (content-disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf) and content type as application/pdf mime.

Comment: So why don't you skip the base64 and simply embed with url pointing at file on server? Or an endpoint that serves the whole file

Comment: @charlietfl I simply can't. for security reasons I am not exposing a dynamic folder where I can point urls to contents in it. I know this is stupid, but it remains there until I figure out a work around.

Comment: You don't need to expose directory if you use a server side script to deliver file and secure that script

Comment: @charlietfl can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Elaborate on what? have an endpoint serve the whole file instead of base64 version and embed that endpoint url. Lots of ways to make that url unique and secure by numerous different approaches depending on use case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170956/discussion-between-myonaiz-and-charlietfl).

Comment: @charlietfl if you place your comment as answer I will mark it as the correct answer. thanks a lot!